# Using the required attribute in HTML5 with a Button submit

Tags: html, forms, button, submit, required

I am having a stupid issue with a form. I have always used the 'required' attribute in an input box for quick validation, but now for some reason when I am using a button instead, the validation is not running? Does it just not work with a button or am i doing something wrong? Something that could be causing issues, is that the the required fields are sometimes readonly. Is there maybe a conflict? Below is some example code:

This would be my input box:
    `<input type='text' id='something' name='something' required />`

and this would be my submit:
    `<input type='submit' value='Submit' />`

But now I am trying to use this:
    `<button type='submit'>Submit</button>`

Thanks in advance. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Which browsers do you see this problem with?

Comment: I'm developing in Firefox. I added to the question though, that maybe is it because it would be readonly as well sometimes?

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle?

Comment: Works fine for me (tried latest Chrome and Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/rjhbD/1/

Comment: That code works just fine, but it is when there is readonly as well as required that it gives issues.

Comment: Ahh, well that could be the problem. Theoretically speaking how would user enter something in the field if it's readonly, so browsers probably don't set required flag if the field is set to readonly

Comment: It's a strange situation, I know. Its a form and you click a button to edit the data which makes all the fields editable, and then when you're done editing, the fields become readonly again. I need a way to stop them being edited but still be required.

Comment: Would it not be easiest simply to remove the `readonly` property in the `submit()` method/handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same issue, you cannot have required and readonly in an input field. Just try do without or maybe use some JavaScript to help out.